# Concatenate string in groupby with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id  v1  v2
1   a   b
1   a   d
2   c   e
2   d   e
2   f   g
```

which can be created with the command:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,2],'v1':['a','a','c','d','f'],'v2':['b','d','e','e','g']})
```

I need to concatenate v1 and v2 using comma in each id group, with one conditions:

- If a value already exists in the group, and it's the only value in the group, do not concatenate it.
  So the output should look like:

```
id  v1  v2
1   a   b,d
2   c,d,f   e,e,g
```

In this case, when id=2, v2="e,e,g", both "e" stay because e is not the only value in this group. However, when id=1, v1="a", because "a" is the only value in this group.

I have done concatenation part, but I am not sure how to implement the conditions. Here is my code so far:

```
df.groupby(['id'])[['v1', 'v2']].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add an if statement inside your lambda function.

```
print (df.groupby(['id'])[['v1', 'v2']].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)) if len(set(x))==1 else ', '.join(x)).reset_index())
```

If the set(x) has only one element, then you just pass set(x) else you join the values.

The output of this will be:

```
   id       v1       v2
0   1        a     b, d
1   2  c, d, f  e, e, g
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Comment: Why the join when `len(set(x)) == 1`? Isn't the join only needed to the right of the if, not the left?

Comment: Now I see.  The first .join is simply to get the item out of the set.  `print(df.groupby(['id'])[['v1', 'v2']].agg(lambda x: next(iter(set(x))) if len(set(x))==1 else ', '.join(x)).reset_index())` also works, and has the maintenance advantage of only needing to set the delimiter in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try

```
g=df.groupby('id').agg(list)
```